Clarifai - Getting 400 error when running face-detection
When I put in a URL and run the API call, I get a 400 error specifically pointing out the fetch() function. I am unsure what I am doing wrong or if my code is wrong. My current code:
import { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import FaceRecognition from './components/FaceRecognition'
import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm'
import Logo from './components/Logo'
import Navigation from './components/Navigation'
import Rank from './components/Rank'

function App() {
  const [imageInput, setImageInput] = useState('');
  const [imageURL, setImageURL] = useState('');

  const returnClarifyRequestOptions = (imageURL) => {
    const PAT = '123456778956332';
    const USER_ID = 'username';
    const APP_ID = 'appname';
    const IMAGE_URL = imageURL;

    const raw = JSON.stringify({
      "user_app_id": {
        "user_id": USER_ID,
        "app_id": APP_ID
      },
      "inputs": [
        {
          "data": {
            "image": {
              "url": IMAGE_URL
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Key ' + PAT
      },
      body: raw
    };

    return requestOptions;
  }

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setImageInput(event.target.value);
  }

  const onButtonSubmit = () => {
    setImageURL(imageInput);
    fetch("https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/" + 'face-detection' + "/outputs", returnClarifyRequestOptions(imageInput))
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Navigation />
      <Logo />
      <Rank />
      <ImageLinkForm
        handleChange={handleChange}
        onButtonSubmit={onButtonSubmit}
      />
      <FaceRecognition imageUrl={imageURL} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App

I have tried changing my PAT, my App ID, and changing the setting on my clarifai app but I have not had any luck on figuring out the issue at hand. I also tried hard coding some URL value to see if it works, but I am not sure what to change.

Are you trying to make the calls from a browser? It sounds like you might be running into a CORS error. If that's the case, you could try moving your API call to the server side, or you could launch your browser in a security bypass mode, like it’s explained here: Disable same origin policy in Chrome.
